# replaceWith not working for option to optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can not replace option tag to optgroup tag using Jquery replaceWith.

The code i tried so far,

```
<select id="SelectboxId">
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="Bombae">Bombae</option>
    <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
    <option value="US">US</option>
    <option value="California">California</option>
    <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
</select>
```

```
var oSrc = document.getElementById('SelectboxId')
for (var i = 0; i < oSrc.options.length; i++) {
    if (oSrc.options[i].text=="India" | oSrc.options[i].text=="US") {
        $("#SelectboxId").find('option[value="India"]').replaceWith('<optgroup> India <optgroup/>');
        $("#SelectboxId").find('option[value="US"]').replaceWith('<optgroup> US <optgroup/>');
    }
}
```

**Note :** There is a way `<optgroup value="India">India</optgroup>` but i want to do using replaceWith dynamically.

Tell me where i am wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually looking for the [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap) method.

For example:

```
 $("#SelectboxId option[value='India']").wrap("<optgroup/>)");
```

---

From the looks of it, what you actually want to do is to group the states from same country in an `<optgroup>`.

For that first you need a way to indicate to which country an option belongs to. You can use a class or a data attribute for that purpose. Then you can use [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll) method as follows:

```js
$("#SelectboxId [data-group='india']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='India'/>");
$("#SelectboxId [data-group='US']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='US'/>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectboxId">
  <option value="Bombae" data-group="india">Bombae</option>
  <option value="Chennai" data-group="india">Chennai</option>
  <option value="California" data-group="US">California</option>
  <option value="Delaware" data-group="US">Delaware</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you.Its working fine but chnage the code to $("#SelectboxId option[value='India']").wrap("<optgroup label='India'/>");

Answer (score 0):

My Jquery solution goes here

```
$("#SelectboxId > option").each(function() {
    if (this.text=="India" || this.text=="US") {
$("#SelectboxId").find('option[value="India"]').replaceWith('<optgroup> India </optgroup>'); 
$("#SelectboxId").find('option[value="US"]').replaceWith('<optgroup> US </optgroup>');
    }
});
```

working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/raghuchandrasorab/ozmqt32s/